# WP database tables rapidly changing

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site (currently running 3.9.1) that has a few tables in which the number of containing rows changes rapidly and seemingly dramatically.  The total number of rows in my *_commentmeta* and *_postmeta* tables will increase/decrease in the tens of thousands in a couple of seconds.  My *_comments* table also changes, but its activity is less dramatic than the other two previously mentioned.

This is not a high traffic web site.  I took at a look at the real-time analytics and when there are zero current visitors it will still do this.

I have a test site in which I duplicated the fileset and database for this site and it's behaving the same way.  I have deactivated plugins and that didn't stop it.  I then removed the fileset from the server entirely and it was still doing it.  I checked the server to see if there were any cron jobs I didn't know about automatically doing things relating to the database and nothing.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this continual rapid change in the size of these tables?

***UPDATE:*** these database tables are still changing even after removing the web site files from the server.  I looked into if there was an [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) active (using "SELECT @@event_scheduler" query) but it was off.

Comment: How are you determining the number of rows? InnoDB?

Comment: I'm looking at them in PHPMyAdmin and hitting refresh every second or two to notice how quickly they change that fast.

Comment: The engine being used for all specified tables is InnoDB (if that helps).

Comment: Can you see what's in the new rows?

Comment: @msturdy unfortunately things change so quickly I could not successfully see content that is changing.  I tried in PHPMyAdmin many times with no success to do so.